# Prove that the series converges

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_n)$ be a bounded positive and monotone increasing sequence.

I need to show that $\sum (1-\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}})$ converges.

My approach was as follows:

Let $B=sup (a_n)$

Then since the sequence is monotone increasing $1-\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\leq 1-\frac{a_n}{B}$

for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

By the ratio test we then have

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left | \frac{1-\frac{a_{n+1}}{B}}{1-\frac{a_n}{B}} \right |=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left | \frac{B-a_{n+1}}{B-a_n} \right |< 1$$

Which implies the series converges. The problem I can see is that if the sequence is not strictly increasing, L might yield 1 and the test would be inconclusive.

Is there a diffrent approach to this problem?

Comment: Even if the sequence is strictly increasing, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{B-a_{n+1}}{B-a_n} = 1$ is possible.

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$1-\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_{n+1}}\le\frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_{1}}$$
and the telescoping series
$$\sum_n{a_{n+1}-a_n}$$
is convergent since the sequence $(a_n)$ is convergent so the given series is convergent by comparison.

Comment: You're welcome Karpov.

Comment: Excellent synopsis, dear Sami!

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $(a_n)_n$ necessarily converges to some $l$, hence the ratio test used in the OP attempt is not conclusive.

However, since $0\leqslant \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_{n+1}}\leqslant \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{a_1}$, the $N$-th partial sum is bounded by $\frac{a_{N+1}-a_1}{a_1}$, which is itself bounded by $\sup_N(a_{N+1}-a_N)$.

Comment: Aren't the N-th partial sums bounded by $sup_N(a_{N+1}-a_1)$